Flutter http.Response get wrong character value
I am using the following code to get my data. However, when if my string consists of special symbol/character (), some of the special symbols/character will become some other weird character. I did try to debug code where I form the response and everything works perfectly. But the response body I printed out from flutter returns me the weird character . Can anyone know how could this happen and what I should do to get my expected results?
Example:
Sample & Expected string:
-/:;()£&@.,?!’[]{}#%^*+=_\\|~<>€¥•.,?!’

Output string from response:
-/:;()Â£&@.,?!â€™[]{}#%^*+=_\\|~<>â‚¬$Â¥â€¢.,?!â€™

Sample code on how to call the API:
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var streamedResponse = await request.send()
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);


The issue you're experiencing is related to character encoding. When you receive the response from the API, the special characters are not being decoded correctly.
import 'dart:convert';

// Decode the response body using UTF-8 encoding
var decodedBody = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);


I upvoted Chris's answer, but for anyone wondering how to then parse the decoded body for json, here's a full parse response function:
 static Map<String, dynamic> _handleResponse(http.Response response) {
    // decodes the bytes properly to get good results
    final decodedBody = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(decodedBody);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to perform operation: ${response.body}');
    }
  }

